# Sega Genesis MegaDrive \ 32X emulator with GUI for ROM selection and management

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, game, emulator

I've tried the **[Gens32](http://www.gens.me/downloads.shtml)** and **[Kega Fusion](http://www.carpeludum.com/kega-fusion/)** emulators but their user interface is too simple for my expectations, I would like to have a **Sega Genesis** emulator with personalization and rom management features...

For that reason, I'm in search of a standalone **Sega Genesis** emulator or a multiple console emulator (like **MAME** which is only for Arcade systems not consoles) that accomplishes these requisites:

- Free.
- For Windows.
- Can emulate at least MegaDrive roms and optionally MegaDrive 32X roms.
- Can run roms in fullscreen.
- Has a save state/load state feature and supports SRAM (Save RAM) for MegaDrive.
- Support **[Game Genie](http://gamegenie.com/cheats/gamegenie/genesis/index.html)** codes for Mega Drive roms (.pat files)
- Support Japanese, USA and European MegaDrive roms.

  (sure weird since MegaDrive console has not a BIOS, just an OS ROM)
- This is the most important need:

  Has a graphical user interface on which I can sort and manage my roms with useful info (by name at least), and display artwork (titles, snaps) like for example **[MameUI](http://www.mameui.info/)** can do, something similar like this:

[image]

---

### UPDATE

I've discovered and tried **[Romulus - ROM Manager](http://romulus.net63.net/)**, which is a ROM manager on which you just add the console roms (after building a database file using the same program) and then I can assign an emulator to run my roms, so in theory with **Romulus** I could have a GUI to list my roms and show their images and then I select a rom to run it externally using **Kega Fusion** emulator, this combination of programs will cover all the requisites I need, seems **Romulus** has promising features:

[image]

HOWEVER, I spent few hours trying to discover how the hell I can set the images (manually, from scratch) for my roms, I'm very lost with this program...

This is a relevant sample of the database file (in Xml format) that **Romulus** creates for my Sega Genesis ROMS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE datafile PUBLIC "" "">
<datafile build="" debug="no">
    <header>
        <name>MegaDrive Roms</name>
        <description>MegaDrive Roms</description>
        <version></version>
        <date>9/10/2016</date>
        <author></author>
        <category></category>
        <homeweb></homeweb>
        <email></email>
    </header>
    ...
    <game name="Alien Soldier">
        <description>Alien Soldier</description>
        <rom name="Alien Soldier.gen" size="2097152" crc="0496E06C"/>
    </game>
    ...
</datafile>
```

I just tried to imagine how to specify a image (or image set) for a single rom, so I added a `Image name` key in the Xml file:

```
<game name="Alien Soldier">
    <description>Alien Soldier</description>
    <rom name="Alien Soldier.gen" size="2097152" crc="0496E06C"/>
    <image name="Alien Soldier.jpg"/>
</game>
```

Then I put the corresponding image inside the **Alien Soldier.zip** file together with the **Alien Soldier.gen** rom file, I loaded the database into **Romulus**, didn't worked (any image is shown when selecting that ROM). I tried to repeat the same procedure with other common key names and with other common image formats such as bmp or png, anything worked.

In the official website the author **[published a tutorial](http://romulus.net63.net/tutorial/tutorial.html)** but it doesn't explain anything of this, and also the "*Offlinelist Updater Button*" [image] is disabled by default so I can't try what he says about that.

In resume, I didn't found the way to show images for my roms using **Romulus**.

A step-by-step explanation of how to use **Romulus** to show images for my MegaDrive ROMs would be considered as a accepted answer from my side, because with **Romulus** ROM manager and **Kega Fusion** emulator I can cover all the requisites mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I play the Sega 32x games for a while and I use the Kega Fusion Emulator and I was very satisfied with the performance. I try other [Sega 32x Emulators](https://www.retrostic.com/emulators/sega-32x) like the RetroArch but for the beginners I highly recommend the Kega Fusion.